# DBT Jinja – for loop with union – skip iteration if table doesn't exist

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

I would like to know how to skip an iteration in a DBT jinja loop that contains a query, if the table doesn't exist and the query fails.

In my example below, I loop over a list of customers  (the var('customers') that is set at the top) and union the tables into one big table. Let's say that in the middle of the list there is a customer for which the table doesn't exist, I will like to just ignore, skip the iteration and continue the loop that unions tables from all customers.

```
{{ config(materialized='table') }}

{% for customer in var('customers') %}
{% set dataset = 'kafka_connect_eu' %}

  select 
        table_id,
        '{{ customer }}'                                                    as client_fk,
        columnABC
 
  from `{{ dataset }}.{{ customer }}_public_tablename`

{% if not loop.last -%} union all {%- endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

With the current code, if the table doesn't exist, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeException Runtime Error in rpc request (from remote system) 404 Not found: Table data-lake:kafka_connect_eu.customerxyz_public_tablename was not found in location EU (job ID: blablabla)
```

If anyone has an idea, that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the existence of the relation before including it.

```
{{ config(materialized='table') }}

{% for customer in var('customers') %}
{% set dataset = 'kafka_connect_eu' %}

{%- set dest_relation=adapter.get_relation(database=target.database, schema=dataset , identifier=customer ~ "_public_tablename") -%}
{%- if dest_relation is not none -%}
  select 
        table_id,
        '{{ customer }}'                                                    as client_fk,
        columnABC
 
  from {{ dest_relation }}

{% if not loop.last -%} union all {%- endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You will need to put a little more sophisticated logic to handle the case where the last customer in your list doesn't exist. I would probably put a `select null, null, null` and then place the loop inside of a subquery and then filter out nulls in the outer query.

Comment: Perfect works thanks a lot!